# How to repeat the flow of entrance of text in C?

Tags: c, function

I made a loop not to repeat everything again and again. But it whenever I try to enter my name, it does not allow me and process cancel. How to do this?

```
int new_acc(FILE * fp, char *name, size_t namesize, char *dob, size_t dobsize){
    int one_by_one;
    char listing[8][15] = {"Name","Date of birth"};
    char another_list[8][15]  = {"name","dob"};         //   These two
    char list_size[8][15] = {"namesize","dobsize"};    //    lines are having problem.

    for (int i=0; i<one_by_one; i++){
        printf("Enter your %s: ",listing + i);
        fgets(another_list + i, list_size, stdin);
    }

    /* This is without loop printing */
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, namesize, stdin);
    fputs(name, fp);

    printf("Enter your Date of Birth: ");
    fgets(dob, dobsize, stdin);
    fputs(dob, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This array has space for 8 lines of 14 + null-terminator characters, so you must be careful when setting your `ono_by_one variable, which by the way, is uninitialized, that is also a problem.

It should be initialized wit a value `> 1` and `< 8`.

There is also no need to initialize it since you are going to overwrite the strings you stored there, make it:

```
char another_list[8][15];
```

This line:

```
fgets(another_list + i, list_size, stdin);
```

Is not correct, the second argument expects the size of the string to be read, which should be no bigger than the container in which it will be stored, so it should look something like:

```
fgets(another_list[i], sizeof(another_list[i]), stdin);
```

This line:

```
printf("Enter your %s: ",listing + i);
```

doesn't make much sense since listing only has 2 lines, so `one_by_one` should be no greater than 2. It will print `"Name"` in the first iteration and `"Date of birth"` in the second and then nothing or whatever gabage it finds in the memry it will read from, this is undefined behaviour.

So the whole code should be:

```
int new_acc(FILE * fp, char *name, size_t namesize, char *dob, size_t dobsize){

    int one_by_one = 8;
    char listing[][15] = {"Name","Date of birth"}; //the number of line can be ommited
    char another_list[8][15];
    char list_size[8][15] = {"namesize","dobsize"};

    for (int i=0; i< one_by_one; i++){
        printf("Enter your %s: ",listing + i); // needs to be changed
        fgets(another_list[i], sizeof(another_list[i]), stdin);
    }

    //here I can't help since I don't know the state of the arguments you 
    //will be passing to the funnction
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, namesize, stdin);
    fputs(name, fp);

    printf("Enter your Date of Birth: ");
    fgets(dob, dobsize, stdin);
    fputs(dob, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```